# Eclipse how to toggle special character in editor

Tags: eclipse

When coding, i usually use hotkey.

Today, I make a mistake on hotkey and my editor show special charaters in every line of code (see the image below):

[image]

Can you tell me how to turn it off?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the 'Show Whitespace Characters' button on the toolbar:
[image]